# A question on Edgeworth Expansion

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, asymptotics, convex-optimization

I'm working Edgeworth Expansion. I couldn't understand one thing . Can you help me about that please.

$$Z= \frac{\sqrt {n} (\bar {x} -\mu)}{\sigma}$$ converges in distribution to N(0,1)

I have found that $\phi_z(t)=\{ \phi(\frac{t}{\sigma\sqrt n })\}^n exp(\{\frac{-\sqrt {nit} \mu}{\sigma })\})$

and we have cumulant generating function is;

$$K_z(t)=n e_n \{\phi(\frac{t}{\sigma\sqrt n })\}-\frac{\sqrt {nit} \mu}{\sigma } = n \sum_{j=2}^infty(\frac{it}{\sigma\sqrt n })^j  \frac{K_j(x)}{J!}$$

$$=-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{K_3(x)(it)^3}{6\sigma^3 \sqrt n}+\frac{K_4(x)(it)^4}{24\sigma^4 n}+O(n^{-3/2})$$

$$\varpi_z(t) = exp\{-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{n^{-1/2}K_3(x)(it)^3}{3! \sigma^3}+\frac{K_4(x)(it)^4}{24n\sigma^4}+O(n^{-3/2})\} $$

$$f_z(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi } \int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-itz}\varpi _z(t)dt=\frac{1}{2\pi }  \int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-itz}exp(K_z(t))dt $$

$$=\frac{1}{2\pi } \int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-itz}exp\{-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{n^{-1/2}K_3(x)(it)^3}{3! \sigma^3}+\frac{K_4(x)(it)^4}{24n\sigma^4}+O(n^{-3/2})\}dt$$

I have show that this is equal to this;

$$=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-itz}exp^{-t^2/2}[1+ \frac{(it)^3 P_3}{6\sqrt n}+ \frac{(it)^4 P_4}{24n} +\frac{(it)^6 P_3^2}{72 n}+O(n^{-3/2})]dt$$

But I could not understand where $\frac{(it)^6P_3^2}{72n}$ comes from ?

Note that $P_j$= ${K_j(x)} \over \sigma^j $